# How to measure the cache miss of the process in virtual machine？

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm, cpu-cache, perf

I used to measure the cache misses of a certain process using `perf_event_open()`.
Now I need to measure cache misses of the process in the virtual machine in similar way.
But `perf_event_open()` regards the virtual machine at just one process.
It seems that `perf kvm` can do it. But can I do it using code?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot measure cache-misses of a process running in the virtual machine if you run the `perf_event_open()` system call on the host.

The host and the guest (i.e. VM) do not share a kernel, and you do not have a way to obtain performance characteristics of a process running inside the VM, from the host. Any `perf kvm` event you run on the host can only measure the performance characteristics of the virtual machine as a whole, and not particularly, any process ruuning inside it. More details [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perf-kvm).

You should run `perf` directly inside the guest. You can use the `perf_event_open()` system call manually through your program and run it inside the VM only. Of course, this may need you to enable the [VPMU](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/sect-virtualization_tuning_optimization_guide-monitoring_tools-vpmu) for the guest and also, if your host CPU supports virtualization of PMU counters, run the VM with `cpu=host`.